# What is the difference between search, searchByImage and compare in AWS Recognition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

I need to use AWS Rekognition service in my app to verify the user and get them logged in into the app. I ended up in a confusion with the API which has 3 options available, the one is called `search`, `searchByImage`, and the other one is called `compare`.

What is the difference between the methods above? And which one is the most suitable for authentication purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Rekognition.html) seems to be clear enough and in my opinion `searchByImage` would be the better than `search` option for authentication process. For a similar application I used `idexFaces` method first to index images of user and then used `searchByImage` method, but the thing is photograph could be used to log in into the app.

Comment: I did read the documentation before but I still confused. I'll go try your opinion. Thanks for the answer!